# Getting videoWidth is null error using react-qr-reader@2.2.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, qr-code

I'm using react-qr-reader for scanning qr code, once the scan completes or when I remove the component I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'videoWidth') at Reader.check
```

My code for qr reader, It unmounts when the it scan correct qr.

```
{isRecording && (
  <QrReader
    delay={500}
    onError={handleError}
    onScan={handleScan}
    style={{ width: "400px", heigth: "400px" }}
  />
)}
```